# Camera2 YUV formats efficiency and differences

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I noticed that in Camera2 the [`StreamConfigurationMap.getOutputFormats()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap#getOutputFormats()) function returns different YUV formats depending on the phone's hardware.

For example, my Samsung S21 returns `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888`, as well as `ImageFormat.NV21`.

I was wondering if there are any differences in efficiency, compatibility or feature parity here? E.g. does `NV21` support 60 FPS streaming whereas YUV_420_888 doesn't? Or is this purely just data layout for consuming it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All camera2 devices have to support `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888`, so that's the safest format to target.

It's a flexible format, and can describe `NV21` or `YV21` (or `NV12` or `YV12`, etc) layouts.

Some devices want to also declare specific formats like `NV21`; it's very possible `YUV_420_888` on that device is also the exact same layout, but if you pick `NV21` then you don't have to query the row and pixel strides.

The camera2 API doesn't allow specifying different available features based on the output format, for the most part.  The general exception is RAW output, since it's directly from the sensor and not processed, obviously features like eletronic image stabilization or noise reduction have no impact on RAW data.  But different YUV formats should all have the same feature set available.

It's possible some YUV formats have lower performance overhead than others, if supporting format X requires an internal conversion from ISP's preferred internal format Y.  But there's no real way to query for that today.

Comment: Thanks Eddy - also a good answer. It sucks that Samsung Devices report 60 FPS as supported, but then just crash when you try to use it, I figured it had something to do with the output format but apparently it doesn't.